# Why does Arrays.asList(...).toArray().getClass() give different results in JDK 8 and 9?

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

Why does the following condition return `true` with JDK 8, whereas it returns `false` with JDK 9?

```
String[].class == Arrays.asList("a", "b").toArray().getClass()
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `List` type returned by `asList` is [`Arrays$ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/4fa75d8ad418/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#l4337). The `toArray` method in JDK 8 on that class is:

```
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    return a.clone();
}
```

But in JDK 9+ it is:

```
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, Object[].class);
}
```

In both cases a `String[]` is passed to `asList`, but in the JDK 8 case it is cloned, which retains its array type (`String[]`), and in JDK 9+ it is copied using `Arrays.copyOf` with the explicit new array type of `Object[]`.

This difference means that in JDK 8 `Arrays.asList("a", "b").toArray().getClass()` returns `String[]` and in JDK 9+ it returns `Object[]`, so in JDK 9+ your expression will evaluate to `false`.

The reason for this change comes from [JDK-6260652](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6260652) with the motivation:

> The Collection documentation claims that
>
> ```
> collection.toArray()
> ```
>
> is "identical in function" to
>
> ```
> collection.toArray(new Object[0]);
> ```
>
> However, the implementation of `Arrays.asList` does not follow this: If created with an array of a subtype (e.g. `String[]`), its `toArray()` will return an array of the same type (because it use `clone()`) instead of an `Object[]`.
>
> If one later tries to store non-Strings (or whatever) in that array, an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown.

So this change was made to fix the previous behaviour.

---

If this is a problem for you, the related [release note](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176893) offers this as a work-around:

> If this problem occurs, rewrite the code to use the one-arg form `toArray(T[])`, and provide an instance of the desired array type. This will also eliminate the need for a cast.
>
> ```
> String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
> ```

Comment: It’s so funny that [the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/8deef18bb749/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l144) contains a protection against this misbehavior with reference to this bug report (it’s from 2005) for a long time now, whereas no-one came to the idea of fixing the misbehavior in the first place, apparently…

Comment: Great, thanks for explanation. Unfortunately the method is called within a serialization code of GWT RPC 2.6.1 so I cannot easily switch to the parameterized `toArray` overloading.

Answer (score 12):

I would say that this was a bug in JDK 8 and before that has been fixed.

`List<T>.toArray()` was always declared as returning `Object[]` (see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--)) - that it did in effect return `String[]` in a special case was a mistake.

Comment: That's incorrect. The method has always returned `Object[]` (just look at its return type declaration). It never violated its declared type. Instead it violated its documented runtime behaviour. The difference is a nuance, but an important one.

Comment: The JDK 9 release note on this change is here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-6260652